# Why doesn't matplotlib operate on objects directly?

Tags: matplotlib

Why does matplotlib work the way it does? For example, why do you do this:

```
x = plt.bar([1,2,3,4],[1,2,2,1])
plt.title('Title')
```

Instead of:

```
x = plt.bar([1,2,3,4],[1,2,2,1])
x.title('Title')
```

It seems like plots should be objects that have methods like "title", "xlabel", etc.

It feels unpythonic to me to have functions which don't even take in the object that they operate on as a parameter, but I'm assuming there's a good reason that it works this way?

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib actually has an object oriented API. So the example would be

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar([1,2,3,4],[1,2,2,1])
ax.set_title('Title')
ax.set_xlabel("X-label")
fig.set_facecolor("pink")
```

The object to work on is mostly the [`matplotlib.Axes.axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html), called `ax` here. It has the plotting methods, as well as all kinds of other methods to tweak the graph.

The matplotlib API is very well documented. You will find the respecitive methods and return types that you need for OO-programming in the documentation.

You can then e.g. look at the return type of `ax.bar`, which is a `matplotlib.container.BarContainer` and colorize the second bar like

```
bars = ax.bar([1,2,3,4],[1,2,2,1])
bars[1].set_color("crimson")
```

Pyplot itself is not very pythonic, because it has been designed to resemble the MATLAB language. But under the hood, it normally just calls the respective class methods from the API.